# How much time to have blockchain synced?

Tags: monerod, blockchain-size

I am wondering if there's a command to predict / calculate how much time does bitmonerod.exe still need for a blockchain fully synced.

Currently its 404321/1133160 and my network usually has a download speed of +3mb/s

Any guesses? Thanks!

Comment: I started syncing about 48 hours ago on my 2008 Macbook (1TB HDD), and I'm at about 27% (334460/1218601).

Comment: I have a 2008 Macbook (with a 250GB HDD, with 8GB RAM) and I've managed to complete just over 50% (632985/1218782) over the last 2 days. I’ve found that it stalls or slows down now and then, in which case I shut down monerod and restart the GUI, after which it starts to synchronise again.

It'll take 4 days at this rate, but that's with occasional pauses for several hours if it has stalled whilst I'm not checking it.

I guess that's the price you pay for using an old laptop for the GUI wallet. Since the laptop is used for nothing else these days, it can stay offline for greater security.

Answer (score 8):

> I am wondering if there's a command to predict / calculate how much time does bitmonerod.exe still need for a blockchain fully synced.

This is basically impossible to calculate. Syncing speed depends on a variety of factors, such as type of hard drive (SSD or HDD), computer specifications (old computer versus relatively new computer), and bandwidth.

On a decent computer with an SSD it will take about 1-2 hours. On a decent computer with an HDD it will already take 6-8 hours. If you have a relatively old computer it might take 12 hours to several days even.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a high end computer with 100mbps internet and as of January 12th at 3:45p.m. EST it has been 24 hours and I'm still going just using the monerod.exe

Comment: I am not sure what your definition of a high end computer is but my internet connection is much slower than yours and I can sync from scratch in 3-4 hours on what I consider a low end computer (but with an SSD and a reasonable amount of RAM) Having a SSD really helps.